# I named my company Higher Standard Service, is this proper english?

Tags: names, descriptive-grammar

So i named my company Higher Standard Service because our company motto is to provide a higher standard "of" service. I want to be sure that by leaving out the "of" in the company name i don not sound silly.

Comment: Your company name does not have to be grammatical (nor does a song or book title) but there are certain reserved words you may not use in a UK company name. [Sensitive words for UK company formations](http://www.formationsdirect.com/sensitivewordsforlimitedcompanyformation). One of them is "Standards".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [naming something](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Lawrence: Naming conventions and the rules that govern proper names (onomastics) are often considered germane to language study.

Comment: If I were interpreting the name, I’d read it as “Standard” being a class of service. “Substandard, Standard, Deluxe” for example. Then I’d say that this must provide a level a service on the upper end in the standard range.  (like upper middle-class).  Probably not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As far as company names go, that one, if it is intended to be a *retail* trade name, would sound strange to English-speakers, at least those who speak American English, because it is far too generic. It could be used as the name of a corporate entity, or a wholesale distributorship, but it would be a very unusual retail trade name as they tend to be more idiosyncratic in the hope that the name will be memorable or "catchy".

A few days ago I saw a large wholesale foods delivery truck on the highway. It had Chinese writing on the side with the English name DELICIOUS FOOD COMPANY.

Your name, Higher Standard Service, is not unlike that name.

In the part of the US I live in, there's a company whose corporate name is **Tasty Baking Company**, but their retail trade name is **Tastykake**.  You can see the difference there between the generic and the idiosyncratic quite clearly.